# LS factor in RUSLE model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topography, soil, rusle

While calculating LS factor through Moore and Burch (1986) equation `LS=(flowaccumulation×Cellsize22.13)0.4×(Sinslope0.0896)1.3` in RUSLE model, what should we use in cell size? Is it in meters or degree?